# How to iterate an object inside a Flux and do an operation on it?

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor, reactive-streams

I'm using project reactor and I'd like to perform the following:

```java
    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) {
        Flux.from(KafkaReceiver.create(receiverOptions)
                        .receive()
                        .map(this::getObject)
                        .flatMap(this::iterateElasticWrites)
                        .flatMap(this::writeTheWholeObjectToS3)
        ).subscribe();
    }

    // What I'd like to do - but a non reactive code
    private Publisher<MyObj> iterateElasticWrites(MyObj message) {
        for (MyDoc file: message.getDocs()) {
            writeElasticDoc(file.getText());
        }
        return Mono.just(message);
    }
```

I'm struggling in finding out the equivalent of the `iterateElasticWrites` in Project Reactor. I'd like to perform an iteration of an object of mine (`MyObj`), and write each of its documents list's element into elasticsearch reactively.

Comment: `flatMapIterable()` ? So, you just do in your stream: `.flatMapIterable(myObj::getDocs)`. Then your `iterateElasticWrites()` would deal with a single `MyDoc`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Reactor you always need to construct a reactive flow using different operators and all reactive/async code should return `Mono` or `Flux`.

Looking at your example it could look like

```
private Mono<MyObj> iterateElasticWrites(MyObj message) {
    return Flux.fromIterable(message.getDocs())
            .flatMap(doc -> writeElasticDoc(doc.getText()))
            .thenReturn(message);
}
```

where `writeElasticDoc` could be defined as

```
private Mono<Void> writeElasticDoc(String text) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: the key aspect on top of that is that you need an asynchronous non-blocking mean of writing the doc to Elastic (and later to s3). As a last resort you should switch to the boundedElasticScheduler before the first `flatMap` with  `.publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())`

Comment: but its considered fine returning the value with `then(Mono.just(message))`? Doesn't it create a new publisher?

Comment: It this example we are returning original object `Mono<MyObj>` but if we don't need this object downstream we could simply return`Mono<Void>`.  There is nothing wrong with using `then()`. It's commonly used to execute publishers sequentially that are not dependent to each other  then -> then -> then.

Comment: Hi Alex, I don't have "thenReturn" method, is it deprecated?